# Raised a flag and the very next moment it was rectified

Tags: discussion, flags

I raised a flag on a question which was very poorly formatted. But soon after the flag was raised it was edit and nicely formatted. I feel bad about it. What can I do?

Comment: You don't raise for _poorly formatted questions_ unless there is a _good reason_ (spam, offensive, ...) to flag it.

Comment: Wait, Think before you flag. Flags are taken very seriously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this kind of condition, I do one of following things :-

- Edit the question
- Leave a comment for OP to edit it. Mark the question as favorite and come back again after sometime to check if it is edited. If not, then I raise the flag.
- Downvote the post.

P.S. I was going to post this in comments, but then I thought, it might be more appropriate to post this as an answer. Feel free to share your views.

Comment: Its `OP`, not `PO`

Comment: This is more helpful. Thanks! I have a new perspective to look at things now!!!!

Comment: @Kedarnath `Owner of Post` or `Post Owner` does it really makes a difference? If I understand full form correctly. If not, please correct me. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: OP = original post / original poster. Searching for *post owner* indicates that the term is not used very often.

Comment: @Stijn thanks, now, I think everybody here has learned something new. :)

Answer (score 2):

VLQ ( Very Low Quality ) flag is supposed to only be used if you think that the post **can't** be improved through editing. It's when there is a non-sense text that is not recognizable or it's a hate/racist or spam. VLQ flags put whatever you flag at a risk of getting deleted from site so you really have to think before you flag it if what can/cannot be improved and deleted. Therefore please remember not to flag *badly formatted* questions as low quality ones.

If you're over 2K+ you're already trusted enough to simply click (Edit) below to question and improve it. If you are less than 2K+ you can still submit your proposal for an edit ( Suggested Edits ) and it ends up in a queue where more experience users judge on the usefulness of your suggested edit. If they approve your suggestion you even receive +2 rep points for it.

*Side note: when improving a question/answer please try to improve all the minor and major issues you can find in a post. For example do not just capitalize the first letter of title and submit for an approval if there are other things to fix within the post. If you see lots of typos, code not properly formatted, or if you feel that you can make someone's sentence a bit clearer then go ahead and do all of that :)*

If you don't want to improve the post yourself for any reason, you may downvote the post, leave a comment for OP kindly asking to improve his question, or use a custom moderation flag (but only if it is *really that necessary*...)